# Extending twig for generate html code

Tags: symfony, twig

I have to generate something like star rating and I have to generate some html for styling ect.

```
        <div class="star on"><i>*</i></div>
        <div class="star on"><i>*</i></div>
        <div class="star on"><i>*</i></div>
        <div class="star"><i></i></div>
        <div class="star"><i></i></div>
```

I want to render using a twig function passing active stars parameters.

```
{{ stars(4) }}
```

Is correct use twig functions for generate html code?
Or maybe should I use {% include ... %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [*Extending Twig*](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) section of its docs. According to the table in the first section on that page, using functions for content generation is natural. I create a lot of Twig functions and I suggest you create one to solve your problem.

BTW, your function can render a separate template with HTML code — do not generate the HTML code right in your Twig function's PHP code. To render a separate template from your Twig function, inject the `service_container` service into it, get the `templating` service and call the `render()` method on it:

```php
return $this->container->get('templating')->render($pathToYourCustomTemplate);
```

Usually, it's best to inject the needed services individually, but if you inject the `templating` service instead of `service_container`, you'll get a cyclic dependencies problem. That's why injecting the whole container into Twig extensions is a reasonable exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer elnur! I've created the twig function, but I generated the html inside php function. Can you tell me where I can find in docs how to render a separate template with html?

Answer (score 4):

No need in overengineering for such simple task.

If you generate your array in Controller, then it could look like this:

```
$stars = array(
    true,
    true,
    true,
    false,
    false,
);
```

Then you could render your HTML in Twig:

```
{% for star in stars %}
    <div class="star{{ star ? ' on' }}"<i>{{ star ? '*' }}</i></div>
{% endfor %}
```

In case if you would like to operate with Twig only, I recommend you to use [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html#macro):

```
{% macro stars(stars, total) %}
    {% for item in 1..total %}
        {{ item }}<br>
        {% if item <= stars %}
            <div class="star on"><i>*</i></div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="star"><i></i></div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

If you've defined your macro in the same template, you should call it via `_self`, if in another file - just like a function, but not forget to `import` your file into needed twig. See chapter about macros (linked above).

Following call will produce HTML structure that you described in your question:

```
{{ _self.stars(3,5) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't have an array in the controller, just an integer ex. 5 for generate 5 stars. I'm evaluating use a twig function because I don't need to repeat the foreach block and other logic related. I render this stars in many templates. I think the macro solution is better, but I can't define the macro in each template. DRY!!. and then I need to import the macro in every template. Why do you say use a function is a overengineering?

Comment: You don't have to define macro in each template. You have to define it once, and then just import it. Its common practice.. And - I say that function/macro is overeng. since I think it is possible to reach your goal using controller and native twig methods :)